# How to send audio file (mp3 or WAV) from app to server?

Tags: java, android, http, android-volley

I'm trying to send an mp3 file that is a recording that my app does, from the app to a server that I made. Been using volley to send requests that were only with strings, but now I need to send the file.
Been trying to convert the file to byte array and to send it, but it seems that the conversion from the file to byte array is not right.

```
private byte[] fileToBytes() {
    byte[] bytes = null;
    File audioFile = new File(mPathSave);
    try {

        bytes = Files.readAllBytes(audioFile.toPath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bytes;
}

private void isCorrectAnswer(MediaRecorder iRecorder, final Button iButton) {
    String url = "myUrl";
    File file = new File(mPathSave);
    try {
        InputStream inFile = new FileInputStream(mPathSave);
        byte[] bytes = fileToBytes();

        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        jsonBody.put("answer", mQuestion.GetmAnswer());
        jsonBody.put("email", "email@email.com");
        jsonBody.put("audio_file", bytes);
        final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
        final JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest =
                new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonBody,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                                iButton.setText(response.toString());
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        System.out.print("ERROR!");
                    }
                });
        queue.add(jsonRequest);


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Update**:
The file is being converted to this:

> [B@5bc86d4

But what i need it to be converted to is something like this:

> b'\x00\x00\x00\x18ftypmp42\x00\x00\x00\x00isommp42\x00\x00\x02\xf6moov\x00\x00\x00lmvhd\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd9X\x87\xf9\xd9X\x87\xf9\x00\x00\x03\xe8\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00wmeta\x00\x00\x00!hdlr\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00mdta\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00+keys\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x1bmdtacom.android.version\x00\x00\x00#ilst\x00\x00\x00\x1b\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x13data\x00\x00\x00\…

(it's really long, but you can see the difference...)

Comment: Did you get any error or exception? if so could you please update the question with that?

Comment: hi, have you tried this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239252/how-can-i-send-an-audio-file-to-be-store-in-a-server

Comment: use a multipart request

Comment: @ksap i've updated the output in the question :)

Comment: @a_local_nobody I wanted to try it but couldn't get Android Studio to recognize HttpClient

Comment: yeah you need to add the dependency for it in gradle, i'm really bad with this type of stuff though (sadly) not the one which should be helping you :D

Comment: implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.0.1")

Comment: `jsonBody.put("audio_file", bytes);` results in you sending the `Object.toString` representation of `bytes`. `[B` means the type `byte[]`, and `5bc86d4` is the hash code of that particular object. You'll have to find (or write) a function that converts the contents of `bytes` into a string in the format your server expects. The put that string into your `JSONObject` instead of the `byte[]`.

Comment: @Michael thank you so much this was the problem!

Comment: The file is *not* being converted to `[B@5bc86d4`. That only results from your erroneous use of `toString()` on the byte array. Copy the bytes.

Comment: did you find an answer for this ?

Answer (score 0):

use multipart request like this

```
private SimpleMultiPartRequest smr;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
```

**MainActivity:**

```
mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


 private void imageUpload(final String imagePath) {

    smr = new SimpleMultiPartRequest(Request.Method.POST, Globalvariable.BASE_URL + "api/profile/image",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("Response", response);

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(com.android.volley.error.VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


    smr.addFile("Image", imagePath);
    smr.addMultipartParam("Id","multipart/form-data",userid);

    //MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(smr);
    mRequestQueue.add(smr);
 }
```

Comment: I don't see how this would help. The issue isn't that the request data gets cut off - it's that he sends the `Object.toString` representation of the `byte[]` (i.e. the class name and the object's hash code) instead of a string representation of the actual array contents.